# telerik mvc datepicker change right-to-left

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik datepicker for mvc. Default render right-to-left. how change from right-to-left to left-to-right UI?

Comment: At first I thought it depends on the configuration of culture, but after the change I did not get the result

Comment: are u adding the class `t-rtl` to parent container of datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Telerik rtl support does not depend upon the culture. it rather looks for `rtl` class in the parent container of any Telerik controler. if class is present it will render the control right to left. For more information plz visit [telerik docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-right-to-left-support.html)

Comment: thank u. I copied the example and saw that there was prescribed class t-rtl